# ADB status offline

Tags: android, usb, adb

My phone is 'device' when I enter abd status-server but when I run an application from Eclipse, the environment install the APK but then my phone is offline. I have to switch it off from the USB and switch it on then.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

you have to kill the adb process from task manager, it will autorestart after you plug in your phone. it sometimes freezes up like that

Comment: ok, then you must use another USB port

Comment: I can't... the others doesn't work... I hace two adb.exe working in my windows... is that right?

Comment: i think there should only be one instance of the adb.exe process running. That may be your problem. terminate both processes and test again after

Answer (score 1):

Try different USB cable. Had this problem too, was using cable from my Logitech mouse. Then I used classic one from local store and it worked...